# Can Apple Silicon run Windows x86?

Tags: windows, parallels, arm

So I'm very confused.

Parallels says they can run Windows on the recent Apple computers with M1 processor, but it seems only Windows ARM can be installed.

But it's not clear if I can run regular x86 apps in Windows ARM. Actually, is this possible or not?

Comment: https://www.theverge.com/22383598/parallels-desktop-mac-windows-10-install-m1-macbook

Comment: I partially addressed this issue back in January [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1616058/buy-a-windows-oem-license-to-gain-access-to-windows-arm-builds-in-order-to-play/1616243#1616243).  Windows 10 (which is entirely different than **Windows 10 on ARM** is incompatible with Apple ARM silicone.  This incompatibility also applies to Windows 11.

Comment: @Ramhound so basically Parallels for the new M1 Macs is useless, as it can't run x86 applications.

Comment: You asked if Apple silicone supports x86/x64 based Windows editions.  It does not, that does not mean, Windows 10 on ARM doesn't support x86 applications.  I carefully worded my comment, your take away from that comment, is entirely inaccurate.

Comment: @Ramhound It's simple, i've been trying to find out if i can actually run my regular x86 apps on Parallels on new M1 Macs. Not even Parallels support gave me a definitive answer. By reading other answers here i think the answer is no, at least at the moment.

Comment: @delphirules - You asked about Windows.  You made no mention of x86 applications.  Windows 10 on ARM has some support for x86 and x64 Windows desktop applications.  My comment was clear what I was saying isn’t compatible.  Since you have accepted an answer I won’t be returning to this question.

Comment: @Ramhound I asked about x86, as you can see on the question title : "Can Apple Silicon run Windows x86?"

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Not really, i know Parallels can emulate Windows ARM, but right now of course most of popular Windows apps are x86, not ARM

Comment: @delphirules Makes sense. I never took a deep dive into Parallels running Windows. Now I did thanks to this question. I want there to be some M1-based way to emulate an Intel chip as well since my development and sysadmin processes depend in VirtualBox and Vagrant running CentOS and Ubuntu. What a damned headache!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I'm in the same situation. I've been using Macs for more than a decade but i need both systems (Mac OS and Win) in my job. Now i'm stuck with my last Imac as i can't upgrade it and will have to stick with it as much as possible, otherwise i'll need two computers, a Mac AND a Win :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 for ARM64 virtual machine only works with a limited set of apps.

From
[Windows 10 ARM-based PCs FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-arm-based-pcs-faq-477f51df-2e3b-f68f-31b0-06f5e4f8ebb5):

> - **Drivers for hardware, games and apps will only work if they're designed for a Windows 10 ARM-based PC.** For more info, check with
>   the hardware manufacturer or the organization that developed the
>   driver. Drivers are software programs that communicate with hardware
>   devices—they're commonly used for antivirus and antimalware software,
>   printing or PDF software, assistive technologies, CD and DVD
>   utilities, and virtualization software.   If a driver doesn’t work,
>   the app or hardware that relies on it won’t work either (at least not
>   fully). Peripherals and devices only work if the drivers they depend
>   on are built into Windows 10, or if the hardware developer has
>   released ARM64 drivers for the device.
> - **64-bit (x64) apps won’t work.** You'll need 64-bit (ARM64) apps, 32-bit (ARM32) apps, or 32-bit (x86) apps. You can usually find 32-bit
>   (x86) versions of apps, but some app developers only offer 64-bit
>   (x64) apps.
> - **Certain games won’t work.** Games and apps won't work if they use a version of OpenGL greater than 1.1, or if they rely on "anti-cheat"
>   drivers that haven't been made for Windows 10 ARM-based PCs. Check
>   with your game publisher to see if a game will work.
> - **Apps that customize the Windows experience might have problems.** This includes some input method editors (IMEs), assistive
>   technologies, and cloud storage apps. The organization that develops
>   the app determines whether their app will work on a Windows 10
>   ARM-based PC.
> - **Some third-party antivirus software can’t be installed.** You won't be able to install some third-party antivirus software on a
>   Windows 10 ARM-based PC. However, Windows Security will help keep you
>   safe for the supported lifetime of your Windows 10 device.
> - **Windows Fax and Scan isn’t available.** This feature isn’t available on a Windows 10 ARM-based PC.